# polars outer join default null value

Tags: python-polars

https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html

Can I specify the default NULL value for outer joins? Like 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join` method does not currently have an option for setting a default value for nulls.  However, there is an easy way to accomplish this.

Let's say we have this data:

```py
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame({"key": ["a", "b", "d"], "var1": [1, 1, 1]})

df2 = pl.DataFrame({"key": ["a", "b", "c"], "var2": [2, 2, 2]})

df1.join(df2, on="key", how="outer")
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ key ┆ var1 ┆ var2 │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 1    ┆ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ 1    ┆ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c   ┆ null ┆ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ d   ┆ 1    ┆ null │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

To create a different value for the `null` values, simply use this:

```py
df1.join(df2, on="key", how="outer").with_column(pl.all().fill_null(0))
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┐
│ key ┆ var1 ┆ var2 │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 1    ┆ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ 1    ┆ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c   ┆ 0    ┆ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ d   ┆ 1    ┆ 0    │
└─────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: There are some drawbacks to be aware of: 1. This fills all nulls, not just those caused by the join. 2. It converts all columns in which nulls are filled to the same type (as of Polars 0.30.0). So if you pass `0.0` suddenly all columns become `f64` instead of `i64`.